# WSO2 response binary why?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

If using samples axis2Server service is very good. But when I created my own web-service using javax I got  a problem.

I used wso2 esb 4.60 default configuration

**Web service:**

```
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Lpu {
    public boolean scheduleAnAppointment(@WebParam(name = "time") Integer time) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**starting web-service:**

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8090/WebServices/lpu", new Lpu());
    }
}
```

**config esb:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <sequence name="main">
      <in>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8090/WebServices/lpu"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </in>
      <out>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </out>
   </sequence>
</definitions>
```

**response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis2ns1:binary xmlns:axis2ns1="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxTOkVudmVsb3BlIHhtbG5zOlM9Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3NvYXAvZW52ZWxvcGUvIj48UzpCb2R5PjxuczI6c2NoZWR1bGVBbkFwcG9pbnRtZW50UmVzcG9uc2UgeG1sbnM6bnMyPSJodHRwOi8vZmVyLndlYnNlcnZpY2UvIj48cmV0dXJuPmZhbHNlPC9yZXR1cm4+PC9uczI6c2NoZWR1bGVBbkFwcG9pbnRtZW50UmVzcG9uc2U+PC9TOkJvZHk+PC9TOkVudmVsb3BlPg==</axis2ns1:binary>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**I want getting:**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:scheduleAnAppointmentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://lpu.webservice/">
         <return>true</return>
      </ns2:scheduleAnAppointmentResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**my reguest**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fer="http://lpu.webservice/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <lpu:scheduleAnAppointment>
         <time>12</time>
      </lpu:scheduleAnAppointment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESB 4.6.0 released with pass through transport, which doesnt build the message. So, if you use the log mediator in the sequence you will get the binary response. But at client end you should receive your response in the preferred format.

If you switch to NIO transport, in the sequence also you can get the actual message payload. For that you need to edit the transport sender and receiver in axis2 configuration(axis2.conf)

Comment: If I used defult simple axis2 service http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/ESB+Samples+Setup#ESBSamplesSetup-StartingSampleBack-EndServices http://codepaste.ru/14606/ and request http://codepaste.ru/14604 then all is well, why?

Comment: if I remove all from <out> and leave a <send> then is true runs

Comment: this is simple [web-service](http://codepaste.ru/14611/)   and this is simple [config](http://codepaste.ru/14612/) esb wso.   why returns binary?

Comment: transportReceiver - PassThroughHttpListener replaced by HttpCoreNIOListener, and transportSender - PassThroughHttpSender replaced by HttpCoreNIOSender. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change `axis2.xml` to `axis2_nhttp.xml` in
 `/repository/conf/carbon.xml` alter:

```
<ConfigurationFile>${carbon.home}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2_nhttp.xml</ConfigurationFile>
```

Another suggestion decrypting the payload:

[WSO2 responds payload in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144639/wso2-responds-payload-in-binary)