# WSO2 responds payload in binary

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a corportative environment and make changes in axis2.xml and carbon.xml can generate impacts.

My problem is that WSO2 is responding the message in binary as an example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
   <soapenv:Body> 
      <axis2ns1073:binary xmlns:axis2ns1073="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">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</axis2ns1073:binary> 
   </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any way or mediator I can resolve this without much impact on other projects within the ESB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have enabled the binary message builder/formatter..Is there any need to use them?

If you use ESB 4.7.0/4.8.X , all those versions are using Pass thru transport..
What is the ESB version you use? Try disable binary message builder and use default message builders/formatters.

If you use binary builders for any specific requirement then use builder mediator to build message if you want to process the message when it passing through the system.